# Find $k$ such that the area is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, contest-math

> For some positive integers k, the parabola with equation $y = \frac{x^2}{k} - 5$ intersects
>   the circle with equation $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ at exactly three distinct points A, B and C.
>   Determine all such positive integers k for which the area of $\triangle ABC$ is an integer.

Point $A = (0, -5)$ and also, I found that the area is:

$\frac{1}{2} BH$ the area of half the triangle $= \frac{1}{2} xy$ so just multiply by $2$ in the end.

In the end, I ended with the coordinate for $B$ as

$B = (\sqrt{10k + k^2}, 5 + k)$.

So the area of the WHOLE Triangle (ABC) is:

$A = \sqrt{k}\sqrt{10 + k}(10 + k)$

Which value of $k$ that will make this an integer is the hard part.

Then I found that:

$A = (10 + k)\sqrt{(k + 5)^2 - 25}$ but I still cannot proceed.

Comment: You really have done all the hard work.  It remains only to find those positive integers $k$ for which $k(k+10)$ is an integer squared.  Since this is not very much above $k^2$, there are only a few cases to examine.

Comment: $k=8$ works, now I am finding other $k$ @hardmath.

Comment: Note that unless $k$ and $k+10$ have common factors, both $k$ and $k+10$ would need to be perfect squares.  This is most of what I mean by "a few cases to examine".

Comment: @hardmath, mmmm. the answer key says, $k = 1, 2, 5, 8, 9$ works?

Comment: Ah, it seems there was a sign mistake, so $k(10-k)$ should be the perfect square.  Note also the requirement that the parabola must be tangent to the circle, so that there are three distinct points of intersection.  Apparently this condition is met automatically, by the solution $(x,y) = (0,-5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying $x^2+(\frac{x^2}{k}-5)^2=25$ gives
$$x^2(x^2+k^2-10k)=0.$$
In order for this equation to have three distinct real roots, we need to have $10k-k^2\gt 0,$ i.e. $0\lt k\lt 10$.
Then, $$x=0,\pm\sqrt{10k\color{red}{-}k^2}.$$

The area of $\triangle{ABC}$ is given as
$$[\triangle{ABC}]=\frac 12\times 2\sqrt{10k-k^2}\times (5-k+5)=(10-k)\sqrt{k(10-k)}.$$

Checking each of $k=1,2,\cdots, 9$ gives that the answer is $k=\color{red}{1,2,5,8,9}$.